# Where can I find the role definition name for azure role assignment

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to add azure keyvault read access right to the azure app service

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "this" {
  scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  principal_id       = azurerm_linux_web_app.this.identity.0.principal_id
  role_definition_name = "Reader" # Seems not correct 
}
```

Where can I find the correct role_definition_name for different resource type for Terraform? I think the role name is different between and Azure Container Registry and Azure Keyvault?

I found the role-based access control role[on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli) But can I directly use these role names? for example

```
 role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van have a look at the [Azure build in RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004151)

It would come down to:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "this" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_key_vault.this.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_web_app.this.identity.0.principal_id
}
```

This will only work for key vaults that use the [Azure role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004151) permission model.

Comment: Thank Daniel, I did write the code exactly like this, But I cannot get access to the keyvault, the log stream form the App service Azure print out the following error `The user, group or application 'appid=xxx;oid=xxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/xxxx/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'kv-name;location=us'.` And when I list out the role via `az role assignment list --scope /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv-name` I can saw the role with `Key Vault Secrets User`

Comment: I accept your answer because it answered my question: where to find the RBAC role names. Terraform was a bit confusing when using the names of roles. I though terraform has its own interpretation on the role names

Comment: Remember that Key Vault has specific policies (in addition to resource permissions) for accessing keys, secrets and certificates. Use "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" for this to grant access. See example here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy

Comment: Its indeed important to know that this only works for key vaults that use the 'Azure role-based access control permission model as described in the documentation.

I'll edit my answer to reflect this.